# Detect Alt-Tab/Task Switching/ForegroundStaging Window accurately

Tags: winapi

Given a valid `hwnd`, how can we verify if it is indeed the alt-tab window?

One of my previous methods was to get the class of the window that the `hwnd` belongs to, then compare it to these values: `MultitaskingViewFrame`, `ForegroundStaging`, `TaskSwitcherWnd` and `TaskSwitcherOverlayWnd`.

However, I've come to realise that class names are not unique across the system, and indeed one can `RegisterClassEx` a class with the same name as the above names, which means my method above would give false positives.

Comment: Check the [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071008-00/?p=24863) and try `IsAltTabWindow` function.

Comment: Unfortunately, my aim is to accurately detect the Alt-Tab/Task switching/ForegroundStaging window, instead of finding which window ends up in the Alt-Tab list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution to the problem: additionally, filter by process path using [GetWindowModuleFileNameW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowmodulefilenamew).

rough pseudocode:

```rust
if window.class() in [..] && GetWindowModuleFileNameW(window.hwnd) == "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" {
    ignore()
}
```

Processes cannot fake their path, so this works.

Comment: This is a good solution, are you comparing both title "Task Switching" and class name "XamlExplorerHostIslandWindow "  - what about localized Windows versions do these remain same also e.g. in Japanese Win11 ?

Comment: Window title is reliable generally, processes can edit this easily. I remember checking the French locale windows' class names, those that Windows uses such as Task Explorer, Windows Explorer etc are still in English. Perhaps due to the fact that the class names are not exposed to the user normally. Class names can be spoofed as well, which is why the above check to use `GetWindowModuleFileNameW` is used as a better guarantee. I'm not sure about XamlExplorerHostIslandWindow, is that the class name for Explorer under Win11?

Comment: Yes, I am developing for Win11 so that is the new class name used there...  Do you know what was the classname for Win7 ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) function to get the active display information correctly.

```
HWINEVENTHOOK SetWinEventHook(
  DWORD        eventMin,
  DWORD        eventMax,
  HMODULE      hmodWinEventProc,
  WINEVENTPROC pfnWinEventProc,
  DWORD        idProcess,
  DWORD        idThread,
  DWORD        dwFlags
);
```

- 

```
 DWORD        eventMin,
 DWORD        eventMax,
```

It is sufficient to give the [constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/event-constants) **EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND** as arguments.

Comment: I actually get the `hwnd`s from `SetWinEventHook`. Specifically, I set a hook for `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND`. If I press alt-tab, the window switches fast but the callback is fired for the the Task Switcher window and some other invisible window with class ForegroundStaging. I basically want to filter those windows out, but I also need to account for rogue processes that try to masquerade as ForegroundStaging etc.

Answer (score 0):

> If I press alt-tab, the window switches fast but the callback is fired
> for the the Task Switcher window and some other invisible window with
> class ForegroundStaging.

For invisible windows, you can use [IsWindowVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-iswindowvisible) to filter.

For the the Task Switcher window, you can compare their title names to filter.

Some code:

```
void __stdcall Wineventproc(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD idEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    if (event == EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND)
    {
         if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
        {
            TCHAR title[512] = {};
            int index = GetWindowText(hwnd, title, 512);
            if (_tcsncmp(title, TEXT("Task Switching"), 14))
            {
                title[index] = L'\n';
                title[index + 1] = L'\0';
                OutputDebugString(title);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> but I also need to account for rogue processes that try to masquerade
> as ForegroundStaging etc.

This is a complicated question. No antivirus or protection technology is perfect. It takes time to identify and block malicious sites and applications, or trust newly released programs and certificates.  With almost 2 billion websites on the internet and software continuously updated and released, it's impossible to have information about every single site and program.

In other words, it is not easy to efficiently identify the true identity of each unknown application.

Refer: [Unknown – Unrecognized software](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/intelligence/criteria#unknown--unrecognized-software)